# getting info from an MS SQL .bak file

Tags: node.js, t-sql, sql-server-2008, restore, sqlcmd

I am writing an Electron app that, among many other things, restores an unknown .bak file to a MS SQL server and then extracts more information.  In order to do this successfully, I need to extract some info from that .bak file programmatically (so SSMS cannot be used).  I will be using sqlcmd, since that can be run by Electron's node.js backend. Unfortunately, I have a bit of a chicken and egg problem, because it seems I cannot restore a .bak file without knowing things about the paths for the .mdf files specified within the .bak file (that cannot be found without first restoring it).  There is a RESTORE WITH MOVE option, though this seems to also require knowledge of the paths inside the .bak, which cannot be determined from the .bak itself.  How might I get this information, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [`RESTORE FILELISTONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

At [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-for-restoring-recovering-and-managing-backups-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you'll find further statements one can use together with `RESTORE` in order to fetch meta data.

The returned resultset of `FILELISTONLY` will give you the *LogicalName*, the file's type (Data or Log), information about the file group and much more.

The other statements provide other meta data. Just check it out...